# Fiddler filter to hide recurring requests

Tags: filter, fiddler

Is there any way to tell Fiddler not to log requests that have already been sent/logged previously?
Or even to filter them after you stop the capture, so as to get a smaller list to process?

Having a huge list of multiple identical requests is really difficult to debug... 
Seemed simple but after many tries, i couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** 
To clarify things :

I am trying to debug a sort of monitoring system, in which the requests and responses change through time but could be hours and thousands of queries before an event changes the system state, hence the request response data. So i would like to skip logging identical request/response sets.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to write a bit of FiddlerScript (Rules > Customize Rules).

*However*, how exactly do you define "identical"? The same URL? The same request headers? The same response body? etc.

The definition you choose obviously has a significant impact on what the necessary FiddlerScript will look like.

Comment: I have updated the question. If the required FiddlerScript is more than a line long then i am not going to try anything. Otherwise i would be grateful for any extra info.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you consider *identical*? The bytes of the request body? The bytes of the response body? Some header value? Something else?

Comment: Both the bytes of the request and response bodies.